# autoscroll does not work with vbox layout

Tags: extjs, vbox

I need align the formpanels to the center, so I used the vbox layout, and after I used it the autoscroll did not work as before, the code is as below:

```
 Usr.VWPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
        id: null,
        rid: null,
        closable: true,
        autoScroll: true,
        buttonAlign: 'center',
        layout: {
                type:'vbox',
                padding:'5',
                pack:'center',
                align:'center'
        },
        initComponent: function () {
            Ext.apply(this, {
                items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'spacer',
                    height: 16
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'usr.usrform',
                    itemId: 'usr.vwpain.usrformt',
                    width: 600,
                    height: 500
                },
                {
                    xtype:'spacer',
                    height: 16
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'usr.loginform',
                    itemId: 'usr.vwpain.loginform',
                    width: 600
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'spacer',
                    height: 16
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'usr.subsform',
                    itemId: 'usr.vwpain.subsform',
                    width: 600
                }],
...
```

plz advise.

Comment: Found this on the Sencha forums: http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-108868.html

Since VBox doesn't support autoScroll:true the suggestion is that you use anchor. Not sure how you would accomplish that centering though...

Answer (score 2):

the vbox layout will never show the scroller.

[image]

```
{
    xtype: 'window',
    title: 'My Window',
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    layout: 'vbox',
    layoutConfig: {
        pack: 'center',
        align: 'center'
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'My Panel',
            anchor: '80% 100%',
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            autoScroll: true,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    html: 'this isform1',
                    height: 100
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    html: 'this isform1',
                    height: 100
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    html: 'this isform1',
                    height: 100
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: so is there an alternative to align the panels in the center?

Comment: try to put forms into a autoscroll panel, then put it into another panel with center layout or vbox (http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html -->Custorm Layout->Center)

Answer (score 1):

in your `css` you can set your *My Panel* margins to `{0 auto}` which will center the *My Panel* inside the window. This means you don't need a special layout config for your window.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a listener on resize event to get the vertical scroll as for Vbox we have to provide height to get scroll but when window size get change scroller height remain constant.

```
Ext.define('DataConfigurations', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px;',
listeners: {
resize: {
    fn: function(el) {
        this.setHeight(this.up('window').getHeight()-150);  // 150  is extra for my panel coz of headers so have minus it.
        console.log("new height = " +   this.up('window').getHeight()-150);
    }
}
},
title: "Update Data Configurations",
```

Hopes this help.